# Trying to randomize which function runs in discord.py But error occurs

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '')

x = 0

@client.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")

@client.command(aliases=['Signore'])
async def _summon(ctx):
        await ctx.send('Ciao sono Signore Buffo')
    
@client.command(aliases=['Gib'])
async def common_phrases(ctx):
    responses = [
    'Si. Yes.',
    'No. No.',
    'Per favore. Please.',
    'Grazie. Thank you.','Prego. Youre welcome.',
    'Mi scusi. Excuse me.',
    'Mi dispiace. I am sorry.',
    'Buon giorno. Good morning.',
    'Buona sera. Good evening.',
    'Buona notte. Good night.'
    ]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(responses))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "please":
        functions = [Hello(message), Test(message)]
        await random.choice(functions)


@client.event
async def Hello(message):
    if message.content == "quiz":
        global x
        x = 1
        await message.channel.send('what is Hello in italian?')
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send('Would you like to know the answer? (y/n)')
    if message.content == "y" and x == 1:
        await message.channel.send('Ciao')
        x = 0

@client.event
async def Test(message):
    if message.content =="test":
        global x
        x = 2
        await message.channel.send('This is a test')
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send('this is a test (2)')
    if message.content == "bruh" and x == 2:
        await message.channel.send('test complete')
        x = 0




client.run('normally code here')
```

When I run the code and type "please" into discord it gives me the error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Hello' was never awaited
  await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I don't know how to fix this and I want to have a randomly chosen function run when I type "please". I tried to put the functions in a list and choose randomly between them. I think it's the on_message function which is giving me trouble. I am new to coding discord bots so this may be a really simple fix. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you running or defining a function `Hello` anywhere?

Comment: Yeah right here

```@client.event
async def Hello(message):
    if message.content == "quiz":
        global x
        x = 1
        await message.channel.send('what is Hello in italian?')
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send('Would you like to know the answer? (y/n)')
    if message.content == "y" and x == 1:
        await message.channel.send('Ciao')
        x = 0
```

its the second function from the bottom

Comment: please edit your question to include that. It is unreadable in the comments

Comment: Sorry the formatting is weird on comments, its the second function from the bottom.

Comment: AH got it, you cannot define your own client.events, like `Hello` or `Test`, [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=events#event-reference) is a list of valid discord.py events.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "please":
        functions = [Hello(message), Test(message)]
        await random.choice(functions)
```

That list doesn't store the address of the two functions, it actually CALLS both functions and stores their result.  You want:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "please":
        functions = [Hello, Test]
        await random.choice(functions)(message)
```

So, `random.choice` returns a function (we don't know which one), and we want to call that function and await the result.

That's a perfectly valid way to choose between several functions.

Comment: I replaced the old code with the new code, when I run it and type "please" in discord it doesn't send anything but doesn't give an error either.

Comment: The functions wont run properly anyways, the `on_message` checks if the content is `please` and Hello checks if it is `quiz`, so if you just say `please`, the if condition inside Hello will fail

Comment: I took off the if statements and it worked, thanks a bunch